# Altair and Panel: Save as button not showing

Tags: panel, altair

I am using the Python library Altair to plot and let the user save as SVG file. To import data and interactive configuration I wanted to use the Panel library. They integrate well but the button to save is missing when I put the Altair plot inside a Panel element. Other interactivity works fine.
This seems to be a general problem as I can find no images of Altair plots inside a Panel element having the save button. However, I cannot find anybody addressing this specific issue, so the question is there any way to resurrect the button so the user can save?

(I know about altair_saver for programmatically saving, but unfortunately we cannot allow the dependencies on our system)

Here is a simple example of Altair with and without Panel.
[image]

And here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
alt.__version__

import panel as pn
pn.extension('vega')
pn.__version__

dictdata = {'variable': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'value': [1, 3, 2, 4] }
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictdata)

chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
   y = alt.Y('variable:N'),
   x = alt.X('value:Q'),
)
chart

pn.Row(chart)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "save button" is known as the *actions menu*, and is configurable in [vega-embed](https://github.com/vega/vega-embed#options) with the `actions` option.

Panel's vega chart embedding explicitly removes the actions by setting `{actions: false}`, as seen here: [panel/models/vega.ts#L71](https://github.com/holoviz/panel/blob/87100776b0f369e3a19bf45d26a18e152a0c3b91/panel/models/vega.ts#L71).

Unfortunately, it does not appear that the package offers any way to configure this. You might try submitting a feature request to the Panel library.

Comment: Thank you for a fast and precise answer - as always. I had tried to set actions to True in my code, but Panel seems to override it.
I will try to submit it as a feature request to the Panel project.